# Separator line after heading in same line

Tags: html, css

I want to add a separator line right after H1 tag, I tried but it's not working, can anyone help?

```
<style>    
    #sepr { 
        border-top-width: 3 px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #FF563A;
        max-width: 18%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>

<h1>Test</h1><div id="sepr"></div>
```

Line is showing above title when I put some text inside `<div id="sepr">`

```
<h1>Test</h1><div id="sepr">Test title</div>
```

Expected result: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is CSS and HTML

```css
body{
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}
.separator{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.separator .line{
  height: 3px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.separator h1{
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div class="line" style="margin-top:12px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities. One would be to work with Flex. Set the wrapper element to flex.
You can then set the line to the correct position with margin-top:XX px;.

The disadvantage is that you always have to adjust margin-top as soon as you have a different font size.

```css
.sepr {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sepr .line {
  flex: 1;
  height: 3px;  
  background-color: #FF563A;
  margin-top:30px;
  
}

.sepr h1 {  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: lightblue;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sepr">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```